# Property 'field' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.entity' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded

Tags: url, odata, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

Running into this issue in Dynamics 365 that seems like it should be working, but gives me:

> Property '_biz_buyerlookupid_value' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.biz_productbuyer' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.

I can copy the example provided here and it works find:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/query-data-web-api#retrieve-related-entities-by-expanding-navigation-properties

Basically trying to read in related fields so I don't have to do another query.

So I have a look up field in a custom entity called `Product Buyer`, or `biz_productbuyers`, to bring in the `Contact` name associated with that `Product`.

The field is called `biz_buyerlookupid` when you look at fields for the entity.

When you use the web API, it says nothing called `biz_buyerlookupid` exists in that entity. Get rid of the `$select=` and run it wide open so I can search for it.

There is a field called `_biz_buyerlookupid_value`. I put that into the `$select` and it returns:

```
{
    @odata.etag: "W/"20636204"",
    _biz_buyerlookupid_value: "906595fd-2a83-dc11-ae20-000feaed3854",
    biz_productbuyerid: "8be67d14-9efb-4335-98c7-000451a50cef",
}
```

Apparently some kind of relationship between the two fields, but it sounds like the `_biz_buyerlookupid_value` is the lookup to `Contacts`. The `_biz_buyerlookupid_value` does correspond with an actual value in the `contact` entity, namely a single `contactid`. I checked. Have tried all of the following and have received the preceding message:

```
/api/data/v9.0/biz_productbuyers?$select=_biz_buyerlookupid_value&$expand=_biz_buyerlookupid_value($select=contactid, fullname)

/api/data/v9.0/biz_productbuyers?$select=_biz_buyerlookupid_value&$expand=biz_productbuyerid($select=contactid, fullname)

/api/data/v9.0/biz_productbuyers?$select=biz_productbuyerid&$expand=biz_productbuyerid($select=contactid, fullname)

/api/data/v9.0/biz_productbuyers?$select=biz_productbuyerid&$expand=_biz_buyerlookupid_value($select=contactid, fullname)
```

So what is going on here? It should be bringing in the `contactid` and `fullname` from the `contact` entity as best as I can tell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My understanding is that the `_[field]_value` item will give you the GUID of the associated item immediately.

To use `$expand` you have to use the schema name, so it should look like:

```
$expand=biz_buyerlookupid($select=contactid, fullname)
```

and note that `biz_buyerlookupid` is case sensitive.

You can look at the metadata for the CRM instance to get the correct casing: https://[org].crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata

Comment: Looking at the `$metadata` was incredibly helpful! From there I could look at the `<Propert Name=>` and then look at the `<NavigationProperty Name=>` associated with the lookup. From there I got the actual name it is using which does appear to be the schema name. Working now!

Comment: Bonus: for anyone needing it in the future, you can combine multiple expands like `$expand=schema_name1($select=field),schema_name2($select=field)`.

Comment: This was driving me nuts, and that metadata link has really opened my eyes and explained some stuff (which really should be visible in the UI somewhere). Time to consolidate all my power automate queries and use expand instead!

Comment: "note that [...] is case sensitive." Wow... just wow. Thanks sir.